# Powermock's Mock Static is not working as expected

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermockito

For my project, I am working on power mock framework for unit testing.
I am facing an issue, I have mocked a static method, but still, it is calling the real method. I have set up the problem with simple classes. Please help to resolve the issue.

This is the Test that is being tested and it has a static method.

```
package in.service;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionClass {
    public static boolean getValue() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "");
        return connection == null;
    }
}
```

This is the test class.

```
package in.service;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DriverManager.class})
public class ConnectionClassTest {
    @Mock
    private Connection connection;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void check_Value_WhenConnectionIsNotPresent() throws SQLException {
        when(DriverManager.getConnection(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(connection);
        ConnectionClass.getValue();
    }

    @Test
    public void check_Value_WhenConnectionIsPresent() throws SQLException {
        when(DriverManager.getConnection(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(null);
        ConnectionClass.getValue();
    }
}
```

When I try to run these tests, DriverManager's actual connection method is called. Ideally, this method shouldn't be called.

Please help here if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: _Don't_ mock statics. Inject a `DataSource` (or equivalent service) into your class.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Can you please share more information on this, may be a link on how to do this?